# Empty Maven Dependency Convergence Report

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependency-management

Using a standard multi-module-project in Maven with a defined dependencyManagement section, even if a (sub-)project defines a different version of a dependency and correspondingly the Convergence (NOD/NOA) in the Dependency Convergence Report is below 100%, but the section of the web site "Dependencies used in modules" is always empty.
In similar project, I have seen the list of non-convergent dependencies, like here:

https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/dependency-convergence.html

What am I missing?

Comment: A dependencyManagement does not define real dependencies and based on that you can't get a dependency convergence report...?

Comment: ahh, that might be it - however, I am getting all the statistics correctly (NOD/NOA, etc.), so the information is present, just the causing libs are not listed. So is this my misunderstanding? Is the list only generated if there are submodules actually really conflicting with their parent modules and not with the dependencyMgmt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i got the same problem and have found the reason)

The report section "Dependencies used in modules" is empty if org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:**2.8.0** or org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:**2.8.1** is used.

Solution:
use the older version of the plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:**2.7**. A report section 'Dependencies used in sub-projects' is added. This section contains details about the dependency convergence problem in the submodules.

Comment: sound like a bug what about providing a [jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPIR) with the problem you have found and the solution..?

Comment: I can confirm that this is true - thanks a lot, never would have come up with this. But khmarbaise is right, do you know why this changed with 2.8? If not, why not file a bug at their jira?

Comment: To not just delegate tasks, I created the [jira issue MPIR-334](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPIR-334)